# Algorithm for finding the shortest path in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Please help me implement the following algorithm. I am a beginner and this problem knocks me off.

The algorithm should find the shortest path from the top left corner to the bottom right. The bottom right element is always 0. The array is always square (eg 3x3).

You can move along the array only downward or rightward. The current position and the int element, the so-called jump force (for example, if we are at the start at point [0] [0] and the corresponding element is 2, then we can move 2 down (D2 ) -> [2] [0] or 2 to the right (R2) -> [0] [2]). If the force of the jump throws us off the field (for example, a 3x3 array and we stepped onto cell 5, then in any case we fly off the field in both directions), we need to start over and look for another way.

An algorithm should calculate the path/the order in which one must jump/walk in order to reach the end with the least possible number of jumps.

[An example of how the algorithm works (Thus, the path will be [D1, R2, D1] - one move down, two moves to the right and one move down)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbMQ6.png)

I have tried different approaches, now I am struggling with DFS after making up an implicit graph out of input int[][] and the answer I get is not the shortest path. I also heard that dynamic programming might help, but do not know how to implement this.

my code with little test included:

```
public class Main {

int indexError = 0;
int shortestPathLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
List<String> shortestPath = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> allPaths;
List<String> solution = new ArrayList<>();

public List<List<String>> findAllPaths(int[][] map, int D, int R) {
int currentPosition = map[D][R]; //D - down, R - right
 if (currentPosition == 0) {
allPaths.add(solution);
return allPaths;
}
if (D + currentPosition <= indexError) {
solution.add("D" + currentPosition);
findAllPaths(map, D+currentPosition, R);
}
if (R + currentPosition <= indexError) {
solution.add("R" + currentPosition);
findAllPaths(map, D, R+currentPosition);
}
solution = new ArrayList<>();
return allPaths;
}  

public List<String> findPath(int[][] map) {
indexError = map[0].length - 1;
shortestPathLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

List<List<String>> l = findAllPaths(map, 0, 0);
for (List<String> path : l) {
if (path.size() < shortestPathLen) {
    shortestPathLen = path.size();
    shortestPath = path;
}
}
return shortestPath;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Main main = new Main();
// int len = 3;
// int[] array =   {1, 2, 2,
//                 2, 10, 1,
//                 3, 2, 0}; // from example
int len = 9;
int[] array =
            {1, 10, 20, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
            1, 10, 1, 10, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
            1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 2, 1, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 1, 2, 2,
            1, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1, 10, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 2,
            1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 20,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1,
            1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0};
int[][] map = new int[len][len];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    map[i][j] = array[k];
    k++;
  }
}
List result = main.findPath(map);
System.out.println("\n" + result + ", " + result.size() + " jumps");
// = must be [D1, D1, D1, D2, R2, D1, R2, D2, R2, R1, R1], 11 jumps
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or with a Depth First Search approach.

```
public List<List<String>> findAllPaths(int[][] map, int D, int R) {
    System.out.printf("findPath(map, %d, %d) called %n", D, R);
    
    // Get the limits of the map
    int mapSize_Y = map.length;
    int mapSize_X = map[0].length;

    // If given coordinates are not in the map
    // Since the moves are restircted to down and right, no need to check lower border
    if (R >= mapSize_X || D >= mapSize_Y) {
        System.out.printf("Point at (%d, %d) not in the map%n", D, R);
        return null;
    }

    int jumpStrength = map[D][R]; //D - down, R - right

    if (jumpStrength == 0) {
        System.out.printf("Found goal at (%d, %d)%n", D, R);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    // Move forward and call the function recursively
    // Spoken - get all subpaths that are possible from this point on
    var subPathsDown = findAllPaths(map, D + jumpStrength, R);
    System.out.printf("subpaths after findPath(map, %d, %d) returned -> %s%n", D + jumpStrength, R, subPathsDown);
    var subPathsRight = findAllPaths(map, D, R + jumpStrength);
    System.out.printf("subpaths after findPath(map, %d, %d) returned -> %s%n", D, R + jumpStrength, subPathsRight);

    // Add the move that produced the subpaths to the result
    var subPaths = new HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>() {{
        if (Objects.nonNull(subPathsDown)) {
            put("D" + jumpStrength, subPathsDown);
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(subPathsRight)) {
            put("R" + jumpStrength, subPathsRight);
        }
    }};

    // If no further path is found return
    if (MapUtils.isEmpty(subPaths)) {
        System.out.printf("No valid Subpaths at Point (%d, %d) %n", D, R);
        return null;
    }

    // Change key-value structure to a list with the key as first entry
    // and the values of the map value afterwards 
    List<List<String>> result = subPaths.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> {
                if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(e.getValue())) {
                    return Stream.of(new ArrayList<String>() {{
                        add(e.getKey());
                    }});
                }

                return e.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .map(sp -> new ArrayList<String>() {{
                            add(e.getKey());
                            addAll(sp);
                        }});
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;
}
```

Furthermore you can remove all attributes of your *Main*-Class, if you change the *findPath*-Method to:

```
public List<String> findPath(int[][] map) {
    int shortestPathLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<String> shortestPath = new ArrayList<>();

    List<List<String>> l = findAllPaths(map, 0, 0);
    for (List<String> path : l) {
        if (path.size() < shortestPathLen) {
            shortestPathLen = path.size();
            shortestPath = path;
        }
    }
    return shortestPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code (A*-Search) you will not get the optimal solution but almost.

```
//= D1, D1, D1, D2, D2, D1, R1, R2, R1, R2, R1, R1, 12 jumps
```

If you can change the *distanceToGoal()*-Method to deliver a better estimation of the true distance to the goal you will get the optimal solution.

```
public class TestClass {
    private static class Position implements Comparable<Position>{
        private final int[][] map;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();

        /**
         * Some Constructors
        */
        public Position(int[][] map) {
           this(map, 0, 0);
        }

        public Position(Position parent, Consumer<Position> consumer, String action) {
            this(parent.map, parent.x, parent.y);
            consumer.accept(this);

            this.path.addAll(parent.path);
            this.path.add(action);
        }

        private Position(int[][] map, int x, int y) {
            this.map = map;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        /**
         * Returns Jumpforce of current position
         */
        public int getJumpForce() {
            return this.map[this.y][this.x];
        }

        /**
         * Returns steps taken till current position
         */
        public int steps() {
            return CollectionUtils.size(this.path);
        }

        /**
         * Method calculates the estimated way to the goal. In this case the mannhatten distance
         */
        private int distanceToGoal() {
            var height = ArrayUtils.getLength(this.map);
            var width = ArrayUtils.getLength(this.map);
            return (height - (y+1)) + (width - (x+1));
        }

        /**
         * Sum of steps taken and the estimated distance till the goal
         */
        private int totalCosts() {
           return this.steps() + this.distanceToGoal();
        }

        public boolean isGoal() {
            return this.map[this.y][this.x] == 0;
        }
    
        /**
         * Returns a list of all successor states
         */
        public List<Position> successors() {
            var s = new ArrayList<Position>();
            if (ArrayUtils.getLength(this.map) > (this.y + this.getJumpForce())) {
                s.add(new Position(this,
                        p -> p.y += this.getJumpForce(),
                        String.format("D%d", this.getJumpForce())));
            }
            if (ArrayUtils.getLength(map[y]) > (x + this.getJumpForce())) {
                s.add(new Position(this,
                        p -> p.x += this.getJumpForce(),
                        String.format("R%d", this.getJumpForce())));
            }
            return s;
        }

    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Position position = (Position) o;

            return new EqualsBuilder()
                    .append(x, position.x)
                    .append(y, position.y)
                    .isEquals();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                    .append(x)
                    .append(y)
                    .toHashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Position o) {
            return Comparator.comparing(Position::totalCosts).compare(this, o);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.join(", ", path);
        }
    }

    public static Position findShortestPath(int[][] map) {
        var visited = new HashSet<Position>();
        var fringe = new PriorityQueue<Position>(){{
            add(new Position(map));
        }};
    
        // As long as there is a position to check
        while (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(fringe)) {
            // Get that position
            var position = fringe.poll();
            //If we didn't look already at this position
            if (!visited.contains(position)) {
                // Check if its the goal
                if (position.isGoal()) {
                    return position;
                } else {
                    //Mark position as visited
                    visited.add(position);
                    //Add all successors to be checked
                    fringe.addAll(position.successors());
                }
            }
        }
    
        // If no solution is found
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int len = 3;
        // int[] array =   {1, 2, 2,
        //                 2, 10, 1,
        //                 3, 2, 0}; // from example
        int[][] map = { {1, 10, 20, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2},
                        {1, 10, 1, 10, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2},
                        {1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 2, 1, 2, 2},
                        {2, 1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 1, 2, 2},
                        {1, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1, 10, 2, 2},
                        {2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 20, 2},
                        {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 20},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1},
                        {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0} };

        Position position = findShortestPath(map);
        if (Objects.nonNull(position)) {
            System.out.printf("%s, %d jumps%n", position, position.steps());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No solution found");
        }
        // = must be [D1, D1, D1, D2, R2, D1, R2, D2, R2, R1, R1], 11 jumps
    }
```

}